# Qual a tradução para "form-fit"?

Tags: significado, tradução-inglês

Qual é a melhor tradução para Português de *form-fit connection*, i.e., quando dois objetos são mecanicamente encaixados um no outro com recurso a frição e atrito?

Exemplo de conexão "form-fit" entre um veio (*mandrel*) e um tubo

[image: du]

Comment: Isto é uma pergunta de terminologia extremamente específica da engenharia mecánica. A tradução rigorosa para Português Europeu -se houver- estará na literatura especializada, e por experiência o termo em Português Brasileiro não será o mesmo.

Comment: Seria bom incluir a fonte das figuras, encontrei apenas um artigo similar: "*Development of design principles for form-fit joints in lightweight frame structures*", Weddeling et al, 4th International Conference on High Speed Forming – 2010 ([e-print](https://eldorado.tu-dortmund.de/bitstream/2003/27190/1/16.pdf)).

Comment: Em alemão, o termo parece ser *Formschlüssiger* :-) E prováveis sinônimos em inglês incluem: *positive(ly) locking/fitting connection*, *form-fitting connection* e *interlocking connection* (veja outros [aqui](https://www.classicthesaurus.com/form-fit_connection/synonyms) e [aqui](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/Formschl%C3%BCssiger). Secundo o @bad_coder e sugiro que você cheque livros-texto e artigos em português da área.

Comment: Formschlüssiger = literalmente: "que se fecha e faz o fecho em torno da forma". Eu quase diria que este substantivo é em si mesmo reflexivo como os verbos em Português.

Comment: O nome para isto vão ser junção/união/manga mais "qualquer coisa". Depende do material de que for feito, se é térmico, etc...Um canalizador pode saber a resposta, quanto mais específico mais concreto vai ser o termo. Podes procurar em sites de venda de material para casas e ferragens, mas também pode referir-se a uma peça industrial extremamente específica, nesse caso é consultar o catálogo especializado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A princípio pensei numa "Manga Termo-retráctil" (que disparate...)

Acho que o seguinte se aproxima tirado [deste catálogo](https://www.directindustry.com/pt/prod/swisschuck-ag/product-207603-2162447.html):

> um cilindro de força e um tubo de tração - cobrem uma faixa de fixação de Ø 5 mm a Ø 20 mm. Diferentes faixas de fixação podem ser oferecidas

[Este catálogo](http://www.casadacaldeira.com.br/home/produtos/mandril/mandril-para-tubos-de-caldeira/) diz que o próprio mandril é um "mandril expandidor de tubos":

> Mandril expandidor de tubos

Portanto será um mandril de expansão (pelo menos em Português do Brasil) com um tubo de tração, acho que o "form-fit" é designado por "cravamento" ou só "encaixe" [exemplos mais elaborados neste catálogo](https://www.swagelok.com/downloads/WebCatalogs/PT/MS-01-140.pdf) (é questão de pesquisar um pouco mais dentro dos documentos.) Que nome dar ao sulco (groove) indicado na figura com a legenda (b) não sei, mas no documento abaixo parece que lhe chamam "matriz".

Uma resposta mais completa talvez possa ser encontrado [nesta dissertação de mestrado](https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/844820067124267/dissertacao.pdf), que cito:

> LIGAÇÃO MECÂNICA TOPO A TOPO DE COMPONENTES
>   TUBULARES
>
> 4.3.6. Ferramentas para o Processo de Cravação
>
> 4.3.6.1. Ligação Convencional
>
> A cravação é a o termo utilizado para designar o processo pelo qual é obtida a junta da ligação dos componentes. Este processo, como já foi referido anteriormente, é composto por um só passo, que pode ser dividido em duas fases – expansão e fecho. Para a obtenção desta junta, para além da força de compressão produzida pela prensa, são necessários outros intervenientes:
>
> · Matrizes – As matrizes inferior e superior, com um raio interior muito semelhante ao raio exterior dos tubos o que lhes confere uma folga pequena, são as ferramentas que impedem que as extremidades dos tubos se expandam. Têm ainda o papel de promover a criação da gelha, através da instabilidade criada pelo contacto com as extremidades chanfradas dos tubos.
>
> · Mandril – O mandril, que se encontra no interior dos tubos e apresenta também uma folga pequena, tem como objectivo manter a secção interior dos tubos, impedindo que estes se deformem na direcção do interior e assegura que a expansão se dê na direcção radial
>   exterior. Também só assim se assegura que o tubo interior instabilize quando chega à matriz, pois fica impedido de deslizar entre o tubo exterior e o mandril.

Answer (score 2):

Não sou engenheiro e nem técnico mecânico, mas tentarei ajudar.
"Connection" nesse caso específico, parece ser traduzida por "acoplamento" na maioria dos sites que visitei.

> - [Acoplamentos mecânicos](https://blog.acoplastbrasil.com.br/o-que-sao-acoplamentos/) são primordiais para indústrias pois fazem a conexão entre dois sistemas maquinários.
>
> Alguns tipos são:
>
> - Acoplamentos de engrenagem;
> - Acoplamentos de elástico;
> - Acoplamentos de lâminas;
> - Acoplamentos de tambor;
> - Acoplamentos de fole;
> - Acoplamentos de precisão;
> - Acoplamentos miniatura;
> - Acoplamentos de segurança;
> - Acoplamentos rígidos;
> - Acoplamentos hidráulicos.

Este [**link**](https://www.directindustry.com/pt/fabricante-industrial/acoplamento-com-flange-143303.html) mostra a foto de mais de 100 tipos de acoplamento, com suas denominações em língua portuguesa. Talvez você encontre o tipo específico da figura na sua pergunta.

Comment: Eu também tinha pensado nisto, mas acoplamento normalmente é uma terceira peça -rígida- que une outras duas. Recordo terem-me dito uma palavra diferente para as extensões lfexíveis que recobrem, só não consigo lembrar-me da palavra exacta...

Comment: @bad_coder   Na figura acima, a parte mais fina me pareceu ser uma terceira peça. Na verdade, respondi sem ter conhecimento técnico, se estiver errado eu deleto.

Comment: Deixa estar a resposta @Centaurus que enriquece o conjunto. Eu não teria tentado pesquisar uma segunda vez se não tivesses respondido.

Comment: Acoplamento é uma boa tradução, visto que vem de cópula, considerando que uma peça penetra na outra. Verei a lista que menciona.